# Convert SQL query to LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table called `visit` with the following columns:

```
visit_Id
member_Id 
visit_Date 
visit_Time 
visit_DateTime 
visit_Status values like (accepted, refused)
```

I have the following SQL query:

```
string sql = @"SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(visit_Status, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(visit_Status FROM 2))  as Status, COUNT('x') AS Visits
   FROM visits
   WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN '2001-09-08' AND '2009-09-09'
   GROUP BY visit_Status";
```

How can I convert this SQL into LINQ? My entity name is `dbcontext`. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738534.aspx)

```
DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(2001, 9, 8);
DateTime dateTo = new DateTime(2001, 9, 9);

var query = from v in dbcontext.Visits
            where v.visit_Date >= dateFrom && v.visit_Date <= dateTo
            group v by v.visit_Status into vg
            select new
            {
              Status = EntityFunctions.Concat(EntityFunctions.ToUpper(vg.Key[0]),
                                              EntityFunctions.SubString(1, EntityFunctions.Length(vg.Key) -1),
              Visits = vg.Count()
            }
```

Comment: I second that. Guess I missed what he wanted with 'x', but yes this would do just fine.

Comment: @cubicle  I am representing this data in chart ...so i want to display the members count along with status in chart ...count(x) is the number of visits .....

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me what you are trying to do with Count('x')?

```
from v in dbcontext.visits
where v.visit_Date >= "2001-09-08" && v.visitDate <= "2009-09-09"
group by v.visit_Status
select new
{
    Status = string.Concat(char.ToUpper(v.visit_Status[0], v.visit_Status.Substring(1)),
    Visits = //Not sure what 'x' is in your example
}
```

Comment: Sorry more specifically what is 'x' since I don't see that in your table called visit.